# Having trouble dealing with dimensionality errors in my CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm new to tensorflow and am attempting to stray away from the mnist data set and try something a little different. I'm working with the emotion data set [CK+](http://www.consortium.ri.cmu.edu/ckagree/) and can't seem to modify my code to successfully run on this data set. For those who'd like to replicate my work, I found the processed images and labels [here](https://github.com/Hansenq/face-emoticon/tree/master/data). You'll find the images in the ck+ scaled folder and the labels in the processed folder.

We're working with a 265 images that are [256 x 256] in size.

So, here is my code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import urllib
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob
train = []
for filename in glob.glob('/Users/madhavthaker/Documents/CSCI63/Final Project/face-emoticon-master/data/ck+_scaled/*.png'): #assuming gif
    img=np.asarray(Image.open(filename))
    img_flat = img.reshape(img.size)
    train.append(img_flat)

### MNIST EMBEDDINGS ###
ckp_labels = [5, 0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 0, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 3, 5, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 1, 5, 0, 1, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 4, 0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 1, 0, 1, 5, 3, 0, 5, 1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 4, 0, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 5, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 0, 3, 1, 5, 5, 0, 3, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 2, 4, 0, 7, 2, 0, 7, 0, 7, 2, 4, 4, 0, 2, 4, 7, 2]

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
  from urllib.request import urlretrieve
else:
  from urllib import urlretrieve

LOGDIR = 'log3/'
GITHUB_URL ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mamcgrath/TensorBoard-TF-Dev-Summit-Tutorial/master/'

### MNIST EMBEDDINGS ###
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.mnist.read_data_sets(train_dir=LOGDIR + 'data', one_hot=True)
### Get a sprite and labels file for the embedding projector ###
urlretrieve(GITHUB_URL + 'labels_1024.tsv', LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv')
urlretrieve(GITHUB_URL + 'sprite_1024.png', LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png')

# Add convolution layer
def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):
  with tf.name_scope(name):
    #w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, size_in, size_out]), name="W")
    #b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_out]), name="B")
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4, 4, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
    act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
    return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")


# Add fully connected layer
def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
  with tf.name_scope(name):
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
    act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
    tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
    tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
    tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
    return act


def mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_conv, use_two_fc, hparam):

  tf.reset_default_graph()
  tf.set_random_seed(1)
  sess = tf.Session()

  # Setup placeholders, and reshape the data
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256*256], name="x")
  x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 256, 256, 1])
  tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ], name="labels")

  if use_two_conv:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")
    conv_out = conv_layer(conv1, 32, 64, "conv2")
  else:
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 64, "conv")
    conv_out = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

  flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 16 * 16 * 16])


  if use_two_fc:
    fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 16 * 16 * 16, 40, "fc1")
    embedding_input = fc1
    embedding_size = 40
    logits = fc_layer(fc1, 40, 1, "fc2")
  else:
    embedding_input = flattened
    embedding_size = 7*7*64
    logits = fc_layer(flattened, 7*7*64, 10, "fc")

  with tf.name_scope("xent"):
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=y), name="xent")
    tf.summary.scalar("xent", xent)

  with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(xent)

  with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, -1), tf.argmax(y, -1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

  summ = tf.summary.merge_all()


  embedding = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024, embedding_size]), name="test_embedding")
  assignment = embedding.assign(embedding_input)
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR + hparam)
  writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

  config = tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.ProjectorConfig()
  embedding_config = config.embeddings.add()
  embedding_config.tensor_name = embedding.name
  embedding_config.sprite.image_path = LOGDIR + 'sprite_1024.png'
  embedding_config.metadata_path = LOGDIR + 'labels_1024.tsv'
  # Specify the width and height of a single thumbnail.
  embedding_config.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([256, 256])
  tf.contrib.tensorboard.plugins.projector.visualize_embeddings(writer, config)

  for i in range(300):
    if i % 5 == 0:
      [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: train, y: ckp_labels})
      writer.add_summary(s, i)
      print ("train accuracy:", train_accuracy)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train, y: ckp_labels})

def make_hparam_string(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv):
  conv_param = "conv2" if use_two_conv else "conv1"
  fc_param = "fc2" if use_two_fc else "fc1"
  return "lr_%.0E%s%s" % (learning_rate, conv_param, fc_param)

def main():
  # You can try adding some more learning rates
  #for learning_rate in [1E-3, 1E-4, 1E-5]:
  for learning_rate in [1E-4]:

    # Include "False" as a value to try different model architectures
    #for use_two_fc in [True, False]:
    for use_two_fc in [True]:
      #for use_two_conv in [True, False]:
      for use_two_conv in [True]:
        # Construct a hyperparameter string for each one (example: "lr_1E-3fc2conv2")
        hparam = make_hparam_string(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv)
        print('Starting run for %s' % hparam)
        sys.stdout.flush() # this forces print-ed lines to show up.

        # Actually run with the new settings
        mnist_model(learning_rate, use_two_fc, use_two_conv, hparam)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

And here is the error i'm receiving:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[16960,1] labels_size=[1,265]
     [[Node: xent/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](xent/Reshape, xent/Reshape_1)]]
```

What's really confusing to me is why my logits shape is [16960,1]. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, y should be of shape (batch_size): (so (265) in your case; maybe it can also work with (265, 1))

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="labels")
```

And with y not being in one-hot encoding, you have to use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`instead of `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Then: at the end of you 2nd conv layer (and max poolings), image size is (256x256)/2/2=(64,64). With 64 depth, you get 64*64*64 values per sample. But you do `flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 16 * 16 * 16])`, which gives you a tensor of shape `[265*2^6, 16*16*16]` (265*2^6=16960, this is where it comes from). Replace it with `flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 64*64*64])`.

Farther, `logits = fc_layer(fc1, 40, 1, "fc2")` is also a mistake, you should have `logits = fc_layer(fc1, 40, num_classes, "fc2")`, and you seem to have `num_classes = 8`.

These changes should give you logits of shape (265, num_classes), which is what you want for `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

You still have other changes to make for the cases where use_two_fc or use_two_conv are false, I'll let you figure them out. You should really be much more careful with the shape of all your tensors at each step, print them if necessary to check that they are really what you want. Maybe use more variables like num_classes_ batch_size, etc, to make sure things are coherent, and it will be more readable.

Comment: Hey there, your comment helped me solve my initial issue and I focused on finding additional information on how to set up my dimensions for a CNN. Now, I changed my filter in the conv later to (17,17) and changed flattened to `flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 55*55*64])`. My math checks out but I get this error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 6553600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 193600`. But it does end up working with `[-1,64*64*64]`. Having trouble understanding what is happening

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you've changed exactly. Maybe it'll be clearer if you eat your question or start a new one, with all your current code